# Node MCU code is stuck in while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu, code-review

I am using the **Node MCu V3** board ESP8266MOD

Board Manager Version: 2.7.4
Arduino IDE: 1.8.12

My code is stuck in the `while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)`

Here is code:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>        // Include the Wi-Fi library
    
const char* ssid = "ESP8266TestNet";  // The SSID (name) of the Wi-Fi network you want to connect to
const char* password = "ESP8266Test"; // The password of the Wi-Fi network
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Start the Serial communication to send messages to the computer
  delay(10);
  Serial.println('\n');
      
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); // Connect to the network

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid); 
  Serial.println(" ...");

  int i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(++i); Serial.print(' ');
  }
  Serial.println('\n');
  Serial.println("Connection established!");  
  Serial.print("IP address:\t");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); // Send the IP address of the ESP8266 to the computer
}
    
void loop() { 
  delay(10000);
  Serial.println(WiFi.status());
}
```

After downloading the code above for setup connection I am using mobile WiFi for connection.

In the mobile settings I can see the WiFi is connected to the ESP Board but when I monitor the Serial it seems that the code is stuck in the `while` loop.

If I comment out the `while` loop the board is giving a WDT reset.

Any ideas? I have been stuck for a long time.

Here I have attached the tools setting of the Arduino IDE:

[image]

Comment: Are you on a breadboard? Those can interfer badly with wifi, though it's weird that you see the esp connect to the access point... maybe, the connection fails right after it has been established and within the one second interval you're polling the wifi state (smartphones wifi settings are typically not updated immediately). You could try to remove the 1000ms delay for a test

Comment: 1) Make sure the SSID and password match your WiFi Access point. 2) Make sure your WiFI Access Point is operating on 2.4GHz, not on 5GHz band because ESP only supports 2.4GHz.

Comment: "I can see the WiFi is connected to the ESP Board"  - what does that mean? Does your ESP run as Access Point? And if yes, why? NB: The WDT reset occurs because in "delay(10000)" the WDT is not fed, and Soft WDT timeout is much less than 10 seconds.

Comment: the settings in Tool are not right. select NodeMcu 1.0